# Need to render variable from route to use in client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am currently able to use variables in the view that I render from the route but only in the HTML markup. How can I use these same variables in the client-side javascript?

I have this code:

```
<script>
  var socket = io();

if ({{highestBidder}} === {{sessionID}}) {
  socket.on('outbid', function () {
    console.log('You have been outbid');
  });
}

</script>
```

However, the variables are not being passed in correctly because I'm just getting an `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't ! Since most of the data is compiled in the server and rendered as HTML page. But there is work around for this :

1. Create AJAX call. Get whatever data you like with it.
2. Store the variables as hidden field and grab then using JS or jQuery [I don't suggest doing this.]